# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' Django Form

Tags: python, django, int

I have a issue when i submit a form on my checkout view.
first of i have a form on my main view where i ask for quantity of an item. I post the data to my checkout view to make a summary on my front-end.
On my Checkout view i have another form where i ask for email and name, when i try to submit the checkout form i have a typeError.

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Here is my checkout view

```
# My view 
@login_required(login_url='login')
def checkout(request):

    data = request.POST.copy()

    region = data.get('region-select')
    plateform = data.get('plateform-select')
    quantity = data.get('quantity-field')
    quantity = int(quantity)
    price = quantity * 3.99

    context = {
        'region':region,
        'plateform':plateform,
        'quantity':quantity,
        'price':price
    }

    return render(request, 'main/checkout.html', context)
```

I don't understand why this occurs because the data get rendered in my template

```
<h1 class="title is-5" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> {{price|floatformat:2}} EUR </h1>
```

Comment: that means `data.get('quantity-field')` is None, but without giving at least the value of *data* ...

Comment: @bruno I tried to print quantity type and i got str not none

Comment: and what you got ?

Comment: tried this : print(type(data.get('quantity-field'))) and got this <class 'str'>

Comment: so may be the error is elsewhere ? what about to do something like `quantity = data.get('quantity-field')` then `try:` then `quantity = int(quantity)` then  `price = quantity * 3.99` then `except:` then `price = -1` to be sure ?

Comment: I did it and the price is now -1

Comment: did it i have my typeError : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' that got printed back

Comment: Just discovered something when i try to submit my form all values from my context become None

Comment: when i do this the error comes back

Comment: No, because setting price to -1 don't use data from context. The problem is when submitting the checkout form the data from the previous one become none

Comment: The value of quantity was None.

Comment: not surprising ^^ sorry cannot help you more, hope someone else will help you (I deleted some useless remarks)

Comment: no problem ty bro